# How to spawn a second console window and read from and write to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, child-process, read-eval-print-loop

I have a node server which displays logs of stuff happening in the terminal.

I want to put a [repl server](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) in it so I can control the server while it is running.

But I do not want the logs and the repl server to conflict with each other, so I want to put the repl server in a separate window.

However, all methods of making a second console window require that you start another process, and that means I do not have control over the stdio streams. (atleast from what I have tried after doing it myself and after following guides)

Here is my most successful attempt:

(`index.js`)

```js
let repl = require('repl'),
    cp = require('child_process'),

    child = cp.spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", "node", "blank.js"], { detached: true });

repl.start({
    stdin: child.stdin,
    stdout: child.stdout,
    stderr: child.stderr,
    useGlobal: true
});

// example log activity
setInterval(() => console.log(Math.random()), 1000);
```

(`blank.js`)

```js
// keep the window open
setInterval(a=>a,2**31-1);
```

While it spawns a repl server, it does so with the stdio of the parent process' window and the spawned window ends up doing nothing.

Is there a way to just spawn a window that I can read from and write to?

Comment: What do you mean by "window"? That's an artifact of the terminal implementation you are using, not of the process.

Comment: by window i mean the black square with white text on it that pops up on your screen when you open cmd.exe or node.exe. I need a second instance of that but I don't want to start a whole separate process for it

Comment: I don't really know the terminology for it, people seem to use console and terminal interchangeably.

Comment: This conflates reading and writing to a process with reading and writing to a visible console window—which do you need?

Comment: @Taureon terminal is the correct term, or [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) if you want to be technical. "console" is also understood in the OS context, but might be ambiguous in nodejs. However, you seem to misunderstand the responsibilities of the application. It's the operating system that launches the terminal emulator application for you, to then have it run the program you started with the stdin/stdout connected to the window. It's not your nodejs program that controls where it reads from and where the output goes.

Comment: As such, your program definitely will need to spawn a second process, if it is supposed to create a second terminal window, e.g. using `cmd.exe`. Or your program could just use more i/o streams, and wait for the user to open another terminal and connect to those additional streams. How to do this, and what the workflow for the user is, would depend on the operating system and choice of terminal application. I assume you are on Windows? Would you be open to do this with the powershell instead of cmd.exe?

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, hopes this info helps

Node. js is a single-threaded, open-source, cross-platform runtime environment for building fast and scalable server-side and networking applications. It runs on the V8 JavaScript runtime engine, and it uses event-driven, non-blocking I/O architecture, which makes it efficient and suitable for real-time applications.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gdLf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMq2P.png)

Comment: I appreciate that you made an account just to answer this question, but this answer isn't really it. 
In node.js you can spawn a child process and I wanted to know how to hijack the console it spawns so I don't need to deal with cross-process communication (which I feel back to anyway). 
Also you can multithread with node.js with "javascript workers" (which isn't elegant but hey it exists). 
Btw you should change the "enter image description here" texts so people with visual problems can read it with TTS or people with low internet can also understand what it contains!